# How can I left-align the table in pdfLaTeX in TeX Live?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have these two TeX files:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,landscape]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}
Hello.

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable}

\end{document}
```

and the other file autogenerates the data:

```
\begin{longtable}{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}
\caption{A very long table}\\
    \hline
    {% for col in head %}
        \textbf{ {{col | escapeTEXT}} }
        {% if not forloop.last %}
           &
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
    \\
    \hline


    {% for row in table %}
        {% for cell in row %}
            {{ cell | escapeTEXT}}
            {% if not forloop.last %} 
               &
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        \\
        \hline
    {% endfor %}
    \hline

\label{tab:LongtableOne}
\end{longtable}
```

This creates the table in the center which is making the columns less wide. How can I left-align the table?

2. Also, I have to hard-code the columns like this: `{|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}`.

**Is it possible to make that dynamic, like in a loop?**

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\longtable}[l]{...}
```

`[l]` is the specifier for the horizontal alignment. However, for `X` columns it makes no real sense:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{xtab.tex}
\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}*3X@{}}\hline
foo & bar & baz\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,ltxtable}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\LTXtable{\linewidth}{xtab.tex}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried it but my table is still in the center. May be because i use LTX but i don't know. i mean i tried this `\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{2cm}|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|X|}` or u mean something else. do i need write your full line somewhere

Comment: a tabular set with `\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable}` and `X` columns will _always be of the defined width.